# Redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have read a lot and spent a lot of hours trying to reach the right way to set a good htaccess in order to redirect an HTTP site to HTTPS.

There are a lot of tutorials on the Internet, even on Stack Overflow, but some of them seem to be outdated and don't meet good SEO practices.

The scenario is the following one:

- My site has Cloudflare enabled
- My site has a valid SSL on server-side

The current htaccess of my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MYSITE\.cl$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.MYSITE.cl/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?find$ find.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?do$   do.php   [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Options -Indexes
```

and I want to change .htaccess in order to keep my good SEO rank on Google, use the HTTPS and keep the .WWW:

```
#OLD PART
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Non-www to www (NEW PART)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Non-SSL to SSL (NEW PART)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#OLD PART AGAIN
RewriteRule ^/?find$ find.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?do$   do.php   [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Options -Indexes
```

Will this work like a charm? Do you have a better idea? Does my code have any redundancy? I think that I must set Cloudflare SSL parameters to FULL SSL (STRICT). Is that right?

Comment: "Will this work like a charm?" Did you try? What's your experience with it so far?

Answer (score 1):

Since your actual machines are being handled by the Cloudflare based forwarding, you can let them handle the enforced SSL and `www`-prefixing rules instead.

However, if you do plan on the **FULL SSL** feature of cloudflare, you can combine the 2 separate rules into a single one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Notice that I do not rely on the `$1` part of the URI, as matching (and capturing) that is just redundant.

---

Similarly, the next 2 rules can be combined:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(do|find)$ /$1.php [L]
```

You can chose to leave it as `$1.php`, but I prefer giving paths from the doc-root in my rules. It is just a personal preference.

---

Lastly, consider providing some gap between the `Options` directive and the directives provided by `mod-rewrite`. Again, it is another personal habit of mine; but makes it clearer to maintain large rule sets later on.

Comment: @Gerrit0 oh damn! Didn't notice that :/ Fixed now. Thanks :)